# CA cert error when setting up git submodules on PPC Mac 10.5.8

Tags: https, git, osx-leopard, certificate-authority, ppc

I have a git repository with submodules on github, when I try and set up the submodules locally by doing:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

I get this error:

```
error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed while accessing https://github.com/wincent/Command-T.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
Clone of 'https://github.com/wincent/Command-T.git' into submodule path 'dotfiles/vim/bundle/command-t' failed
```

I understand that this is a problem with the CA cert being out of date for Leopard, I have tried to rectify this by first installing a new version of curl with ssl support (now on version7.22), and then when that didn't work I updated my crt as per instructions such as:
http://www.simplicidade.org/notes/archives/2011/06/github_ssl_ca_errors.html

I still get the same error.

I've also tried adjusting the protocol in .gitmodules to git from https but this makes no difference either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> I've also tried adjusting the protocol in .gitmodules to git from https but this makes no difference either. Any ideas?

Then you're still fetching via `https://`, rather than `git://`.  You will need to update the URL in your `.gitmodules` *as well as* the URL listed in `.git/config`.

Regarding your certificate issues, I have a few questions:

- What does `which curl` print out?  What does `which curl-config` print out?
- What does `curl-config --ca` print out?
- Is that the file to which you added the new certificates?

Comment: curl is at the usual: /usr/bin/curl

Comment: the ca file is at: /usr/share/curl

Comment: I'll try changing the urls in .git/config, hopefully that will let me get around this. Thanks!